# python urllib2 can't get correct webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, urllib2

I'm writting a spider using urllib2 and beautifulsoup. But I come across some problems.

1. I can't download the webpage correctly. I tried

   `GET 'http://thesite.html'`,

   `wget 'http://thesite.html'`,

   `curl -O 'http://thesite.html'`,

on linux terminal, but got a lot mass, seems like wrong codec.

2. I then tried using `file_get_contents('http://thesite.html')` and also can't get the correct webpage.
3. Then I tried `urllib2.urlopen('http://thesite.html')`, can't work.
4. can't detect the encoding.

   `s = urllib2.urlopen('http://thesite.html')
   print chardet.detect(s)`

   and outputs `{'confidence':0.0, 'encoding':None}`
5. I also tried python3 with urllib.request, I can get a byte string, but when I try to decode this bytes to utf-8, I got a error message.

Anyone can help me about this? How to get the correct webpage like a web browser.

Comment: I think you'll find that posting an error message or two might go a long way to help people understand your problem.

Comment: The page probably rejects your user-agent. Try changing that.

Comment: I feel like to be a thief, too awkard to post the details.

Comment: How can someone help without knowing the details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you downloading? Is it text, or something binary, e.g. an image?

A binary file might explain why standard tools such as wget and curl return a lot of "mass" (mess?), and `chardet.detect()` will return `{'confidence': 0.0, 'encoding': None}` in that case.

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> import chardet

>>> s = urllib2.urlopen('https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIM9Q.png?s=32&g=1').read()    # your avatar
>>> chardet.detect(s)
{'confidence': 0.0, 'encoding': None}
```

What does the byte string that you got in Python 3 look like?  Otherwise, if you are too coy to post the URL, traceback, or other details, perhaps you can post a little of that string?

Comment: Thank you so much for giving such a detailed answer. I still didn't solve this problem but I finished my work, I changed to crawl another site and didn't see any coding issue. I have to say coding is a big problem on web crawling. I will go on this problem and try to give more details.